# Are all computer viruses man-made?

Tags: theory, artificial-intelligence

I'm curious if the origin of any successful computer virus is known to NOT have an intentional, human originator.  To put it another way, do computer viruses ever "spontaneously" originate through the process of natural selection in the same way biological viruses originate; without an intentional "designer?"

I imagine (though I'm not sure) that it's possible for sufficiently knowledgable software engineer to make use of software engineering tools like neural networks, genetic algorithms, adversarial networks, etc to write a virus according to his/her specifications, but that's not what I want to know.  I want to know if computer viruses ever begin on their own, and if they don't, why not?

The three core tenets of evolution by natural selection are descent with modification, variable fitness, and resource limitation. Some scientists say that wherever these conditions are in place, evolution occurs necessarily.  Importantly, being alive is not a prerequisite, which is why biological viruses continue to evolve even though they are not technically alive.  Richard Dawkins says that thoughts and ideas survive and proliferate through the same mechanism.  So, does computer code ever evolve organically without human intervention to form a successfully self-replicating entity?  If not, why not?

Comment: In what ways are you seeing that computer code satisfies the conditions for the core tenets of natural selection? This is a huge false equivalence. Computer code is not magic. Where are the "descendants"? What resources are limited that code responds to? When does code mutate?

Comment: Ultimately, this is not a security question but a computer science question. You could, and should, ask the same question for any function of code, not just functions that could result in harm.

Comment: @schroeder: Interestingly, [some researchers have studied the evolution of computer viruses](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S019667749790897X).

Comment: @AnthonyLabarre sure, but that's the result of designers reusing code. Not spontaneous mutation or propogation.

Comment: @schroeder, mostly yes, although the use of polymorphic code should be taken into account in this discussion. But I should probably let computer virus experts answer this, which I'm definitely not.

Comment: @AnthonyLabarre polymorphic does not create new functions. It expresses designed functions in new ways. Polymorphic code producing unexpected functionality is a bug, not a feature, and would have been stopped by its designer before it could actually affect expected performance. A shoe factory that can produce a wide range of shoes does not accidentally produce a microwave.

Answer (score 6):

Interesting question. I think the biggest barrier preventing something like that from happening is that **computers are engineered to be extremely robust to random, non-human errors**. Computers will do what programmers instruct them to do, and unless the hardware is being pushed beyond its limits or subjected to extreme environments like cosmic radiation in space, they do not deviate from programmer instruction.

It is necessary for computers to have these near-zero error rates due to the sheer quantity of operations they perform. An error rate of one in a million seems pretty good...until you consider that a modern desktop computer is capable of performing about 100 billion operations per second. A one in a million error rate  would result in 100,000 errors per second, rendering your computer completely unusable due to constant crashes!

The same reasoning applies to storage mediums as well. If you assume that one in a million bits stored on a 1TB drive gets corrupted every day, then that would result in 360 megabytes of corrupted data per year!

The necessary low error rates are achieved through a combination of robust engineering and manufacturing, as well as software tricks to detect and repair errors such as checksums and error-correcting codes. In situations where these measures are insufficient, such as on spacecraft computers where cosmic radiation can wreak havoc, fully redundant computers [check each others' results](https://arstechnica.com/science/2019/11/space-grade-cpus-how-do-you-send-more-computing-power-into-space/) though voting.

Therefore I'd argue that "descent with modification" doesn't really exist here. Computers operate more or less deterministically and without error by design, so it would be very difficult for an unexpected program to spontaneously emerge.

If we designed computers that were much more error-prone, then it would be more likely that such an event could happen. But such a computer is also likely to be pretty useless, so we don't build computers like that.

Comment: Interesting reasoning. On the other hand, DNA is quite robust, too: it also has tricks to detect and repair errors, and most mutations leads to "crashes" instead of creating anything new. Yet we have evolution. Computers just haven't been around for millions of years and haven't started to reproduce. :)

Comment: That is a good point, DNA replication is not sloppy by any means. I found [this paper](https://www.nature.com/scitable/topicpage/dna-replication-and-causes-of-mutation-409/) that says mutation rates vary from 1 in a hundred to 1 in a billion. But I think that even the 1 in a billion rate would not be good enough for computers, because continuing with the assumption of 100 billion operations per second, that is still 100 errors per second! More than enough to throw off any meaningful computation.

Comment: Yes, and mutations can only cause evolution in combination with reproduction: on other types of cells they cause e.g. cancer.

Answer (score 4):

There hasn't been any such virus or worm created so far, that was successful enough, to make a noticeable impact. Let's take a look at the circumstances, why this is probably the case.

1. **Such a virus needs a host program.** Software doesn't start running magically by itself on a computer. And even if it would, the structure of an executable file is too complex to originate by chance without an evolutionary process. Therefore, such a virus can only develop with reasonable chance by random mutations of an existing program.
2. **Self-replicating software is rare.** We need a self-replicating host program, but most software components do not self-replicate, especially not with a high frequency. This is a core requirement for evolution though, because it relies on gradual improvements. Almost all mutations in nature are inferior to their original and will not pass the test of time. It is very rare for a mutation to perform so well, that it surpasses the original in the long run. If the mutated software does not self-replicate frequently, the mutation will not replicate as well.
3. **Programs rarely compete for resources for reproduction.** Let's assume we bypassed issue 1 and 2, meaning we have a mutation in a self-replicating program. Now both the original and the mutated version must find themselves in an environment, where they compete against each other and the mutated version has an advantage. Such scenarios can be designed - which would mean human intervention and is not in scope of this question - but will hardly happen in a real computer environment.
4. **The mutated software must be able to spread to other systems.** The chance for any mutation to happen is already very low in today's computer systems. Hardware has a high fault tolerance, checksum verification is prevalent in many protocols and self-repair mechanisms will detect and fix many errors. This means we need a huge and diverse environment to increase the chance of undetected mutations. And we will need a lot of them, because almost none of them will be successful mutations anyway. To find such an environment, our self-replicating, mutating, with other programs competing host program must be able to spread to other systems as well. Assuming that our local mutations somehow developed a way to communicate with other systems through evolution and maybe even find an exploit to spread is of course pure science fiction. This means, our host program must have been designed to spread itself over the network in the first place.
5. **The process must happen undetected by humans.** The list can be extended with several more technical requirements, but we are already able to see, that almost no potential host software in existence provides the environment for an evolutionary process to take place. But there is one more aspect to consider - human intervention! Let's assume there is such a host software, that undergoes mutations which are spread around and a selection process takes place that benefits fitter copies of the software. Still, most of the mutations will perform worse and not only that - the majority will not work at all. Now we are talking about a software that's running on many machines, so it is probably kind of important to many people. If mutations happen often enough for evolution to occur, there will be a significant amount of copies crashing. People will very likely investigate and identify the flaw, that's allowing the mutations. And since that's a bug and not a feature, it will probably be fixed, which ends our fantasy of random artificial evolution.

Answer (score 3):

This cannot happen for the same reasons a wristwatch can't turn into a microwave given enough time.

Code is deterministic. Undesired states in code follow lines of entropy, not increased complexity.

The best you are going to get is "buggy code" not new functions from the code.

Can ***running*** code degrade to have undesired effects? Sure. But that's not a virus.

Comment: Compilers generate machine code not necessarily in a deterministic way. There are a number of exceptions. But I understand what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

In specialized environment like Core Wars, you have the conditions for evolutionary viruses. The classical core wars is for only two competing programs. But that is or can be expanded. The language is simple enough that random generators can create useful code, reproduction is important for both competitors and done all the time.

Another environment would be the Game of Life. Start with a random field and you will find self-reproducing structures.